# difference between CGContextDrawImage et UIImage drawInRect

Tags: iphone, uiimage

I was wondering which method is the best when there is a need to scale images?
Do you have benchmarks on this?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Internally, `-drawInRect:` will rotate the image into the correct orientation according to the `imageOrientation` property, then flip the image upside down to convert UIKit coordinates into CoreGraphics coordinates.

Then it will call `CGContextDrawImage`.

In this sense, `-drawInRect:` is surely slower. But using `CGContextDrawImage` to target UIKit requires one to do the transformation hassles which may not worth for maintenance.

Comment: Very detailled and instructive answer.
Thanks!